# How to write a json web response to a csv file in python?

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv, jsonparser

Here is a schema of the `json` output which I am trying to parse and write specific fields from it into a `csv` file (Example: cve id, description,....)

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "JSON Schema for NVD Vulnerability Data Feed version 1.1",
"id": "https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/feed/1.1/nvd_cve_feed_json_1.1.schema",
"definitions": {
"def_cpe_name": {
  "description": "CPE name",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cpe22Uri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cpe23Uri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastModifiedDate": {
    "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "cpe23Uri"
  ]
},
"def_cpe_match": {
  "description": "CPE match string or range",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "vulnerable": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "cpe22Uri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cpe23Uri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "versionStartExcluding": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "versionStartIncluding": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "versionEndExcluding": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "versionEndIncluding": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cpe_name": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/def_cpe_name"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "vulnerable",
    "cpe23Uri"
  ]
},
    "def_node": {
        "description": "Defines a node or sub-node in an NVD applicability statement.",
        "properties": {
            "operator": {"type": "string"},
            "negate": {"type": "boolean"},
            "children": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_node"}
            },
            "cpe_match": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_cpe_match"}
            }
        }
    },
    "def_configurations": {
        "description": "Defines the set of product configurations for a NVD applicability statement.",
        "properties": {
            "CVE_data_version": {"type": "string"},
            "nodes": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_node"}
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "CVE_data_version"
        ]
    },
    "def_subscore": {
        "description": "CVSS subscore.",
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 0,
        "maximum": 10
    },
    "def_impact": {
        "description": "Impact scores for a vulnerability as found on NVD.",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "baseMetricV3": {
                "description": "CVSS V3.x score.",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "cvssV3": {"$ref": "cvss-v3.x.json"},
                    "exploitabilityScore": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_subscore"},
                    "impactScore": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_subscore"}
                }
            },
            "baseMetricV2": {
                "description": "CVSS V2.0 score.",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "cvssV2": {"$ref": "cvss-v2.0.json"},
                    "severity": {"type": "string"},
                    "exploitabilityScore": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_subscore"},
                    "impactScore": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_subscore"},
                    "acInsufInfo": {"type": "boolean"},
                    "obtainAllPrivilege": {"type": "boolean"},
                    "obtainUserPrivilege": {"type": "boolean"},
                    "obtainOtherPrivilege": {"type": "boolean"},
                    "userInteractionRequired": {"type": "boolean"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "def_cve_item": {
        "description": "Defines a vulnerability in the NVD data feed.",
        "properties": {
            "cve": {"$ref": "CVE_JSON_4.0_min_1.1.schema"},
            "configurations": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_configurations"},
            "impact": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_impact"},
            "publishedDate": {"type": "string"},
            "lastModifiedDate": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["cve"]
    }
},
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "CVE_data_type": {"type": "string"},
    "CVE_data_format": {"type": "string"},
    "CVE_data_version": {"type": "string"},
    "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs": {
        "description": "NVD adds number of CVE in this feed",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "CVE_data_timestamp": {
        "description": "NVD adds feed date timestamp",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "CVE_Items": {
        "description": "NVD feed array of CVE",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_cve_item"}
    }
},
"required": [
    "CVE_data_type",
    "CVE_data_format",
    "CVE_data_version",
    "CVE_Items"
]
}


    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec  3 17:08:51 2020

@author: Rajat Varshney
"""
import requests, json


api_url = 'https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/'
cveid = input('Enter CVE ID: ')
api_call = requests.get(api_url+cveid)
print(api_call.content)

with open('cve details.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(api_call.content, outfile)
```

Comment: Here is the link to the schema:
https://csrc.nist.gov/schema/nvd/feed/1.1/nvd_cve_feed_json_1.1.schema

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: Also, please don't use tags just because your data is related to them. *Solving your problem* has nothing to do with cyber-security.

Comment: @rajat92: Is there any specific question ?

Comment: I did write a code to make the api call and put the output in a text file, that throws an error too 'TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable'

Added the code in the post.

My next step is to parse that json output in a csv.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just wanted to see if the cyber community had something similar done. Sorry for the trouble, edited the tags :)

Comment: Okay, so the next step is to try putting something like `python requests read json` into a search engine.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel
I guess it was just converting the output to .json() and writing it to a file.
My next step is to write it in a csv. Suggestions on Lists or Dataframes which would be better for this schema?

Comment: Are you searching for a tutorial? I don'T understand the question?

Comment: Well, what do you think you should try putting into a search engine this time? What came up when you did?